# Life on giant planet | Can centrifugal force reduce gravity?

Tags: internal-consistency, planets, physics

In my world a space civilization is colonizing a massive solid planet. 
The planet has an extraordinarily fast rotation. 
The gravity is severe at the poles, making life impossible, but life flourish within a wide belt at the equator. 
This “green belt” is possible thanks to the extreme rotation - the centrifugal force greatly reduces the high gravity.

Is this concept purely fiction or would such a planet (in theory) be possible?

Comment: This is the exact premise of Hal Clement’s 1953 novel _Mission of Gravity_.

Comment: High gravity will make the poles uninhabitable for much Earth life but some Earth life forms like bacteria, as well as native life adapted to the gravity such as flat, pancake like animals, should do just fine at the poles.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Yes**

**Example**

Let's assume we have a planet with the gravitational acceleration of Jupiter and want to reduce it to earths gravitational acceleration.

**Edit**

This is meant as an in practice example of how fast a planet with the size and mass of Jupiter would need to spin to experience same forces as on earth.

**Example continues**

[According to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jupiter) Jupiter has a Gravitational acceleration of $24.79 \;\frac{m}{s^{2}}$. And as we all know Earth has a gravitational acceleration of $9.81\;\frac{m}{s^{2}}$. So the rotation has to cancel out the difference between gravity on earth vs gravity on Jupiter ($24.79 - 9.81 = 14.98$). This means our centripetal acceleration has to be $14.98\;\frac{m}{s^{2}}$.

With this Formula we can determine the speed at which the Planet has to rotate: $a = \frac {v^2}{r}$, where $a$ = acceleration, $v$ = speed and $r$ = radius.

If we take Jupiter as an example again, $r$ would be $71 492 000\;m$. So when we plug in our values we get this: $v^2 = 14.98\;\frac{m}{s^{2}} \cdot 71492000\;m = 1 070 950 160\frac{m^{2}}{s^{2}}$. Because we have $v^2$, we have to take the root of it which gets us to $32 72\;\frac{m}{s}$ speed. Which is about 3 times faster than Jupiter is actually rotating, but possible.

Comment: @AtmosphericPrisonEscape Yes exactly you wouldn't feel it would simply reduce the gravitational pull of the planet and no one would feel the centripetal force. Don't get where your problem is.

Comment: @AtmosphericPrisonEscape I get different values? Which doesn't change my conclusion? Sorry I really don't get it. It is an EXAMPLE.

Comment: @AtmosphericPrisonEscape  My research hasn't shown any reason or even suggestion why this shouldn't work. So It would be helpful to either write an answer your self or tell me where mine is wrong so that I can improve it.

Comment: What would happen to an object approaching the planet that does not feel the effects of centripetal force? I'm sure it would get crushed prior to entering the atmosphere. Next, if it didn't get crushed, and the atmosphere hasn't been stripped away, the 3000 mph winds the planet would have would definitely do so. Not to mention the planet would be bulging at the center.

Comment: @Sonvar These are problems his civilization has to deal with and not about whether it is possible to reduce high gravity.

Comment: @AtmosphericPrisonEscape Even if you disagree, please do so respectfully.

Comment: While the theory is nice, I don't think it would work out that nicely. For starters, the math only really works around equator. As you diverge from equator, the radius relative to the axis of rotation decrease, which changes your equation. Then secondly, as you move away from equator, the vectors don't line up anymore, and thus won't cancel each other.

Comment: @Spoki0 These problems are the core to the question it is his goal to have a belt around the equator where gravity is small enough to sustain life while near the poles there is no life because the lack of centripetal force crushes everything that tries to live there. So the problem is wanted for his scenario.

Comment: The general principle works, but it's not quite that *straightforward* in reality, for the simple reason that the radius of the planet doesn't stay the same as you spin it up--it flattens out. Properly solving for the shape of the equipotential surface and the force of gravity at various latitudes for a given spin rate (let alone *reversing* that calculation) is rather hairy--enough so that even Hal Clement basically punted and assumed the shape of Mesklin was dominated by the gravity of a close-enough-to-spherical degenerate matter core.

Comment: @Sonvar An object approaching the planet won't get crushed until it tries to touch down. Being in freefall, after all, is exactly equivalent to being in zero gravity, as amply demonstrated by the people floating around on the ISS. And 3000mph winds are hardly guaranteed; the atmosphere would for the most part co-rotate with the ground, just like it does on Earth--where you will note that the equator does *not* regularly experience 1000mph winds.

Comment: @Logan Jupiter rotates fairly fast and produces 1000 mph winds. The increased gravity would flatten much of the surface structures, minimizing obstructions so the atmosphere probably won't cooperate as you suggest. The gravitational forces act upon asteroids and do in fact tear them apart, just look at Shoemaker-Leevie asteroid in the '90's.

Comment: @Sonvar Jupiter's winds aren't that fast solely because Jupiter rotates that quickly. They are that fast because there is a continuous input of thermal energy to drive them, Jupiter's fast rotation confines them to latitudinal belts, and there is no solid topography to drain their energy. Given that the whole point of the scenario is that effective gravity near the equator is *low*, the topography would not be flattened there.

Comment: @Sonvar And Shoemaker-Levy was not "crushed" by Jupiter's gravity--it was torn apart by tides. Unless your spaceship is several kilometers long, that won't be an issue--and if it is, your ship just needs to have more tensile strength than a rubble pile to hold itself together, while its center of gravity is still in freefall.

Comment: Crushed, torn apart, you are arguing over semantics. I'm just pointing out that gravitational forces still exist when centripetal forces are not acting on you

Answer (score 6):

If you put a high spin on something squishy like a planet it's going to bulge at the equator and the poles will descend (to keep the volume constant)

Both re-shaping effects themselves reduce surface gravity.  At the poles you have less mass beneath you, and at the equator you're further separated from most of the mass

I don't think my calculus is strong enough to guess the shape, but this guy has some ideas.

https://www.science20.com/robert_inventor/so_you_thought_you_knew_what_spinning_planets_look_like_surprising_shapes_of_rapidly_spinning_planets-155538

Answer (score 4):

> the centrifugal force greatly reduces the high gravity.

Yes, this is a physical concept, and in fact how orbits work. Any small mass $m$ orbiting a large mass $M$ has its centrifugal force balancing gravitational acceleration exactly, so that

$$g = \frac{v^2}{r} $$
and the gravitational acceleration $g$ is the result of the planetary mass $M$, gravitational constant $G$ and distance $r$ via

$$g = \frac{G M}{r^2}$$

so that any velocity that fulfills the force equality is $v^2= \frac{GM}{r}$, also called Keplerian or orbital velocity. Therefore this is the velocity at which centrifugal force can balance gravity. This velocity is only a function of the planet to be orbited and nothing else, particularly no other planet, like @Soans confused answer might suggest. It is $8 km/s$ for Earth's low orbit, and will be much higher for OP's rapidly spinning, high-mass planet.

This has now several important implications:

1. A planet rotating with Keplerian speed at its equator, will not be a stable structure. Its surface would lift off into space.
2. A planet rotating at less than Keplerian speed will feel a reduction in gravity. This reduction will become less and less as one goes from equator to the poles, so the concept in OP's question is also real, but the 'centrifugally assisted life' needs to develop at the equator, otherwise there is always an unstable region on the planet.
   The fine-tuning required for this effect to be viable (also we don't know at which gravity life can function) might make the setting unbelievable.

Comment: Now I get what you meant but your interpretation of the question is simply another. You understood that the question is about how to completely cancel the gravitational force, while I simply thought about partial canceling. The same way it is on earth just scaled up (you weigh about 0.5% less at the equator than at the poles).

Comment: @Soan: Yes the idea is the same for all of us. But why you invoke Jupiter to cancel gravity on Earth centrifugally is completely beyond me.

Comment: No you totally misunderstood my answer. In the scenario that you want an earth like gravity but instead you have a planet with the gravitational force of Jupiter. For this example I calculated the speed at which Jupiter would need to turn in order to reduce its gravitational pull down to the level of earth

Comment: @Soan: In fact, now I understand your intent, but even after re-reading your answer I don't think you communicated it that well. I will however retract my comments below your answer, as with your additional explanation, they are not justified anymore.

Comment: I have edited my answer to better show what this example is for and what forces are achieved with this example.